# Best practice for variable assignment and why?

Tags: python

I was wondering what you guys consider best practice for assigning a variable value. The 'lazy' case:

```
signal = -1
if (date.month != nextDate.month):
    signal = +1
```

or the fully disclosed case:

```
if (date.month != nextDate.month):
    signal = +1
else:
    signal = -1
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages for either case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose the fully disclosed case.

- It clearly indicates that `signal` is assigned based on some conditions (essentially a switch statement)
- those conditions are listed in a tabular format, which is very readable
- single assignment is less error prone than double assignment

It is important to be able to quickly identify what's happening, and the fully disclosed case does that best. Remember, your code will be *read* more times than it is written, so make it easier for future readers of the code.

Comment: +1. This is the easiest case to debug or maintain later on.

Comment: But, if there's any other logic that depends on this, there's a chance more will be inserted into the if/else, and arguably clarity will be lost. Plus, it's harder to see what's going on at a glance.

Comment: Not sure I understand your first point. I disagree with the second one...things that line up (e.g. tables) are a lot easier to read. Your eyes naturally see what `signal` is assigned to in either case.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
signal = -1 if date.month == nextDate.month else 1
```

It's simple and readable.

Comment: thats true but I was trying to get a more generic answer :) The above case doesn't necessarily work for other languages, nor would it work for several conditions where one could still pre-allocate a value. Appreciated though!

Comment: @Muppet:  I would say other languages are out of scope when asking a question tagged with just Python.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, I tend to use the first ("lazy") case. It's more concise, and it's clear what it does.

I actually think that the functional version is better (i.e. python's if expression), and I will try to switch to using it.